# Django - Pagination test

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

When moving a test from a separate class to a class with other tests, it starts showing 4 posts on the second page instead of 3. If range is changed to 12 it shows 2 posts. Please suggest what is the problem.

```
def test_correct_page_context_guest_client(self):


    posts = [Post(text=f'Тестовый текст {i}',
                  group=self.group0,
                  author=self.user0) for i in range(
        13)]
    Post.objects.bulk_create(posts)
    pages = (reverse('posts:posts_list'),
             reverse('posts:group_list',
                     kwargs={'slug': f'{self.group0.slug}'}),
             reverse('posts:profile',
                     kwargs={'username': f'{self.user0.username}'}))
    for page in pages:
        for page_number in range(2):
            with self.subTest(page=page):
                response = self.guest_client0.get(
                    page, {'page': page_number+1})
                self.assertEqual(len(response.context['page_obj']),
                                 POSTS_COUNT[page_number])
```

If the test is left in a separate class PaginatorViewsTest(TestCase): then everything works as it should, but this is the task of the reviewer

Here is the class and SetUpClass in which the test is located

```
class PostPagesTests(TestCase):
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    super().setUpClass()
    cls.user = User.objects.create_user(username='test')
    cls.user2 = User.objects.create_user(username='test2')
    cls.user_unfollow = User.objects.create_user(username='test3')
    cls.guest_client = Client()
    cls.authorized_client = Client()
    cls.authorized_client.force_login(cls.user)
    cls.authorized_client_no_follow = Client()
    cls.authorized_client_no_follow.force_login(cls.user_unfollow)
    cls.guest_client0 = Client()
    cls.user0 = User.objects.create_user(username='auth')
    cls.group0 = Group.objects.create(title='Тестовая группа',
                                      slug='test_group')
    cls.group = Group.objects.create(
        title='test',
        slug='test',
        description='test'
    )
    cls.group2 = Group.objects.create(
        title='test2',
        slug='test2',
        description='test2'
    )
    cls.post = Post.objects.create(
        author=cls.user,
        group=cls.group,
        text='test'
    )
```

Comment: Difficult to say without the rest of the test code, I'm guessing that is probably because there are additional Posts, maybe in the `setUp` method.

Comment: I added class and SetUpClass. Look please

Comment: I see an additional Post created in the `setUpClass` I think that additional Post is causing the discrepancy, consider creating 12 Post instead of 13, or simply change the test to take in count that additional Post.

Comment: Is it possible to change the code so that this Post does not participate in the test I need?

Comment: Yeah, you can delete it as part of your test.

Comment: I don't quite understand how to do it

Comment: In the first line of your `test_correct_page_context_guest_client` you can put `self.post.delete()`

Comment: I tried this method, unfortunately it breaks other tests

Comment: In that case, the best way to solve your problems is to change the test to take in count the additional Post, seems like the expected content for each page is inside `POSTS_COUNT`, I think you need to modify it in some way to pass the test.

Comment: POSTS_COUNT = [10, 3] PAGINATOR_POSTS_COUNT = 13--->AssertionError: 4 != 3
POSTS_COUNT = [10, 3] PAGINATOR_POSTS_COUNT = 12---> AssertionError: 2 != 3
Can't get equality

Answer (score 0):

I added Post created in SetUpClass to SetUp and deleted it before pagination test with self.post.delete() command

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).